# Huawei Matebook D14 intel i3 Fedora 35 no sound

Tags: audio, fedora, huawei-mobile-services

As the title says I do not have sound in Huawei Matebook D14 intel i3 and Fedora 35. Any help and step by step guide appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Check this see if this can help you: https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/content/en-us00698517/

Comment: Thanks a lot, but my original asking is for Fedora 35 linux, and the huawei support link is windows only.